# run adb from virtualbox with win11 host

Tags: android, virtualbox

I have a setup with virtualbox which installed ubuntu20.04. The host is windows11.

When I connect a usb android device to windows11, windows11 can run adb successfully.

What I want is still using the windows11 adb server, but run adb client from virtualbox linux.

It need reverse port forward, which means forward 5037 port from linux to windows. but I try virtualbox port forward settings, it only support forward from windwos to linux.

How can I do reverse port forward from virtualbox to host?